# Collate information missing when converting a MySQL table from Latin1 to UTF8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, internationalization, collation, latin1

I'm converting an existing table such as this:

```
CREATE TABLE `example`(`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                       `column1` char(32) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL 
                           DEFAULT '',   
                       `column2` char(64) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL 
                           DEFAULT '',
                       PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) 
              ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 
              DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

to utf8 using the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE example CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

This seems to work ok, but the resulting table doesn't include any collation information:

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                        `column1` char(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
                        `column2` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
                        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
                        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

So my question is,  would the missing collate information be a problem? I searched google but couldn't find mention of this anywhere. My understanding of the collate flag is pretty basic ( it matters in some way when comparing the characters in string functions I think?)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [default collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-charsets.html) for the `utf8` charset is `utf8_general_ci`, so it's not displaying it.